# return value in boost thread without using boost::promise

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

```
int xxx()
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread th;
    th = boost::thread(xxx);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

How to catch the value returned by the xxx() method without the use of boost::promise?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a promise? The only alternative is to write something that does the same thing, which seems rather pointless.

Comment: Actually i want to change something in main & the method xxx() is not editable

Comment: @Bakkya boost::future?

Comment: @UldisK boost::future can be used only if we use boost::promise. But I dont want to use boost::promise

Comment: @UldisK I got correct solution! please refer to the following answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you can't change `xxx`, call another function which puts the result somewhere accessible. A promise is probably still the best option, but you could write it directly to a local variable if you're careful with synchronisation. For example

```
int result;
th = boost::thread([&]{result = xxx();});

// Careful! result will be modified by the thread.
// Don't access it without synchronisation.

th.join();

// result is now safe to access.
```

As mentioned in the comments, there's a handy `async` function which gives you a future from which to retrieve an asynchronously-called function's return value:

```
auto future = boost::async(boost::launch::async, xxx);
int result = future.get();
```

Comment: The OP could just call do `int result = xxx();` to have this effect. (If there was more work not shown in main, presumably he could just put that work on a thread instead)

Comment: @sehe: You can do something else concurrently with `xxx`, which is presumably why the thread exists.

Comment: As shown the join refutes the concurrency. See the edit to my comment though

Comment: @sehe: You can do something else before the `join`, concurrently with execution of `xxx`, which is presumably why the thread exists. Then `join` when the result is needed.

Comment: Thanks!!!  it is a good approach! if xxx() is present inside the class example, how could i use this method?

Comment: @Bakkya: You mean if it's a member function of a class called `example`? Then the lambda will have to capture a suitable object to call it on, e.g. `[&]{result = my_object.xxx();}` to call it on (a reference to) a local object called `my_object`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Apparently you still missed that edit in the first comment. Anyways, by now I don't see why isn't just `auto x = std::async(&xxx); /*...*/ int fetch_it = x.get();` - same deal except hiding the thread management`

Comment: @sehe: Yes, `std::async` would be equivalent, and perhaps preferable if you don't want to deal with a thread directly. But the use of Boost implies that C++11 might not be available, and I don't think Boost.Thread has an equivalent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe `boost::async` predates `std::async`, I could be wrong on that. At least, `boost::async` clearly exists for a long time and has significantly more (optional) features than the standard library variant

Comment: @sehe: Fair enough, I didn't know there was a `boost::async`, and a quick search didn't find it (although a more careful search [did](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.async)).

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks yaar! this is a great way to use return the value from a method. :)

Comment: without using async itself we can call the thread with the above method to return the value

Answer (score 0):

> Actually i want to change something in main & the method xxx() is not editable

Use a shared object with suitable synchronization (mutex, mutex+condition variable)

A sampler of the options I mentioned (you don't need all of them, obviously):

```
int global = -1;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void xxx()
{
    // do lot of work...

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        global = 5; // safe because lock for exclusive access
        cv.notify_all();
    }

}

int main()
{
    boost::thread th(xxx);

    {
        // need to lock since the thread might be running
        // this might block until `global` is actually set

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        cv.wait(lk, [] { return global != -1; });
        std::cout << "global has been set: " << global << "\n";
    }

    th.join();

    // here there is no locking need
    return global;
}
```

Comment: Or you could simply join the thread when you want the result; that would give the same synchronisation as this over-complicated dance.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If you look closely, you'll see that I actually show precisely that in the sample too (_hint_: `return global`). Also, the answer is in the first line. The code is just sampling the abstractions I mentioned

Comment: OK. To me, the answer seemed to imply that you need the complicated dance, not just a simple `join`, to retrieve the result. Perhaps I was reading too much into it.

Comment: it a good idea to use locks. but as I mentioned before, I dont wanna change the xxx() mwthod

Comment: but by using this way we want to add some changes to the xxx() method